# Compare columns in two text files and match lines

Tags: bash, awk, text-files, text-processing

I want to compare the second column (delimited by a whitespace) in file1:

```
n01443537/n01443537_481.JPEG n01443537
n01629819/n01629819_420.JPEG n01629819
n02883205/n02883205_461.JPEG n02883205
```

With the second column (delimited by a whitespace) in file2:

```
val_8447.JPEG n09256479
val_68.JPEG n01443537
val_1054.JPEG n01629819
val_1542.JPEG n02883205
val_8480.JPEG n03089624
```

If there is a match, I would like to print out the corresponding line of file2.

Desired output in this example:

```
val_68.JPEG n01443537
val_1054.JPEG n01629819
val_1542.JPEG n02883205
```

I tried the following, but the output file is empty:

```
awk -F' ' 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next};c[$2] > 0' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Also tried this, but the result was the same (empty output file):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$2 in a' file1 file2 > file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$NF]; next} $NF in a' file1 file2

val_68.JPEG n01443537
val_1054.JPEG n01629819
val_1542.JPEG n02883205
```

Here is a `grep` alternative with process substitution:

```
grep -f <(awk '{print " " $NF "$"}' file1) file2
```

Using `print " " $NF "$"` to create a regex like `" n01443537$"` so that we match only last column in `grep`.

Comment: Hmm...my output still stays empty unfortunately.  I think the problem might be in my source files. How can I can check whether the columns are actually delimited by a single whitespace in every line? I'm pretty sure they are, but maybe I can check to be sure.

Comment: You can run `cat -vte` on both files and check what characters are present (it could be due to DOS line ending as well)

Comment: We might be on to something here. For file1 I get a `$` appended to every line. For  file2 I get `^M$` appended to every line.

Comment: You can run `dos2unix` on `file2` to fix `^M` or DOS line ending problem

Comment: Otherwise you can run `awk -v RS='[\r\n]+' 'FNR==NR{a[$NF]; next} $NF in a' file1 file2` command

Comment: Excellent,  `dos2unix` did the trick! Your solution works perfectly now, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

GNU `join` exists for this purpose.

`join -o "2.1 2.2" -j 2 <(sort -k 2 file1) <(sort -k 2 file2)`

Comment: Cool, didn't think of using `join`. It doesn't work (yet), however, I think that is due to an issue with my input files.

Comment: 1. It will produce output data not in original order 2. Sorting can be expensive for large files